# Tomcat unable to load class located in dependency jar?

Tags: tomcat, jersey, tomcat7, maven-3, jersey-2.0

I have Jersey defined in the `web.xml` of my webapp A, but the `ResourceConfig` and related classes are located in jar B, referenced as a dependency in webapp A's `pom.xml` file.

So the `web.xml` of web app A has the following section:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>jersey-servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
        <param-value>com.jar.b.CustomResourceConfig</param-value>
    </init-param>
    ...
</servlet>
```

In this case `CustomResourceConfig` is on jar B. Then also on webapp A, the `pom.xml` file lists a dependency on jar B:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.group</groupId>
        <artifactId>com.jar.b</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.0</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
```

I can access classes from jar B from webapp A without problems, since it is a dependency. But Jersey fails to load the `ResourceConfig` configured in `web.xml` with class not found:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.jar.b.CustomResourceConfig
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1702)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1547)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.util.ReflectionHelper$7.run(ReflectionHelper.java:407)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.util.ReflectionHelper$7.run(ReflectionHelper.java:397)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.createResourceConfig(WebComponent.java:453)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.<init>(WebComponent.java:301)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:169)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:359)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1280)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1088)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5481)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I'm attempting to run this setup from Eclipse using a Tomcat 7 server, but it also fails if I deploy it directly into Tomcat. I exported the war and checked the jar is located on the correct location under WEB-INF/lib.

Why is Jersey not able to find that class? Since jar B is a dependency, shouldn't Jersey have access to it's classes when initializing?

Thanks!

Comment: Strange, I assume CustomResourceConfig extends javax.ws.rs.core.Application.  Are the jersey jar files located in the WEB-INF/lib of your webapp as well?

Comment: It does extend javax.ws.rs.core.Application, yeah.. and jersey files are in the lib dir... still a mystery.

Comment: I have pretty much the same setup, except that I don't use maven. When you deploy from Eclipse, though, please remember that you have to add either your jar B or directly the project into the Run/Debug configuration. I'm not in a stage where I have automized the deployment in tomcat7, but in the (successful) trials I've done, basically asking eclipse to generate the war, the only difference is that it has added "<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>" to the servlet definition @ web.xml, but I'd say it does not make a difference at all. Mystery, indeed. Hope at least you get eclipse working.

Comment: BTW I fixed the issue but don't know what was wrong... I rebuilt the project B on eclipse from scratch and pasted in the source files, and that seem to have resolved it... I bet it was something wrong in my project structure. Thanks anyways!